# Ionic 3 sending http post request as application/x-www-form-urlencoded to Django backend

Tags: django, angular, ionic3

I'm trying to make a `post` request to my Django backend with Ionic 3 as the front end app. Right now my post method looks like this:

```
register(username, password, email, first_name, last_name) {
    let url = "https://www.example.com/api/create_user/";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return this.http.post(url,
      {"first_name": first_name,
      "last_name": last_name,
      "email": email,
      "username": username,
      "password": password},
      {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

But Django is receiving it like this: 
`<QueryDict: {'{\n  "first_name": "bob",\n  "last_name": "bob",\n  "email": "bob@bob.bob",\n  "username": "bob",\n  "password": "bob"\n}': ['']}>`
And changing the JSON object to a string. I want to properly send form data on my front end so I don't have to do an janky fixes on my Django backend. I tried to add a `transformRequest` to the header, but this triggers a preflight response because the content-type either gets stripped away or is automatically changed to undefined. How do I change this to properly send the form data so the `QueryDict` isn't so messed up?

Answer (score 0):

So I realized I'm asking the wrong question. It is much easier to keep the request in the ionic app as `application/json` and then on the Django side implement a parser for the JSON on the view the `post` request is being sent to, as shown below:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def some_view:
    # View code here
```